# Debug mySQLi prepared statement -> email not found

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

i try to implement a register form and try to check via php and jQuery if a user already registered with a certain email.

here is my piece of code:

```
if(endsWith($email, 'domain.tld'))
{
    $result = $database->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE ?");
    $result->bind_param('s', $email);
    //echo $email;
    $result->execute();
    //echo $result->execute();
    //echo $result->num_rows;
    //exit();

    if($result->num_rows == 0)
    {
        echo'ok';
    }
    else {
        echo 'duplicate';
    }
    $result->close();
}
else {
    echo 'validation failed';
}
```

I used the commented echos and exit() to debug my code. The problem is that the database holds the user user@domain.tld and the script shows me in the echo "user@domain.tld10". So the statement ist executed successful but no rows are returned. If i execute the statement

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email LIKE "user@domain.tld"
```

i get the id (in this case 11) returned.

My question is, how can i debug this php script better and the biggest question is, why is my scipt not working properly?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: sorry, missed the line $result->execute(); just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use before num_rows

```
  $result->store_result();
```

> The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used
>   mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the
>   statement handle.

[Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

Comment: funny that it worked in another script :/

anyway, thank you!